# Slick 3.0 Avoid Excessive Logging When Unit Testing

Tags: logging, sbt, slick

I have a project where I'm using Slick to model my relational data. I have written few unit tests which leverages H2 database. I have integrated a CI pipeline that runts the unit tests upon every commit to my master branch!

I'm using sbt as my build tool and what I see from the build logs is that it contains loads and loads of log lines with DEBUG messages. These messages are written by the underlying Slick library and I definitely want to get rid of them. I have tried several approaches, but none seems to take effect against those army of DEBUG log statements.

My project is a Play Framework based web project and here is what I have as my dependency in my build.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  ws,
  "io.monix" %% "monix" % "2.1.0",
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "3.2.0",
  "com.typesafe.scala-logging" %% "scala-logging" % "3.4.0",
  "org.scala-lang.modules" % "scala-async_2.11" % "0.9.6",
  "com.zaxxer" % "HikariCP" % "2.4.1",
  "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.1",
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.26",

  // test
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-testkit" % "2.5.2" % Test,
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.1" % Test,
  "com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.4.186" % Test,
"org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "1.5.0" % Test
)
```

I tried the following:

1. Set the logLevel in build.sbt to INFO

   logLevel := Level.Info

Unfortunately that did not have any effect!

2. I used a logback.xml that looks like this:

   ```
   <logger name="scala.slick" level="INFO" />
   <logger name="play" level="INFO" />
   <logger name="application" level="INFO" />
   <logger name="akka" level="INFO" />
   ```

and used the following command when I run my unit tests:

```
sbt -Dlogger.resource=conf/logback.xml clean coverage test coverageReport
```

But strangely, that did not have any effect at all as I still keep seeing those annoying DEBUG statements! I'm using Play Framework 2.5.9!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so this is what I did to get rid of the DEBUG statements from Slick:

Modified my build.sbt dependencies to:

```
  // Dependencies needed for Slick
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "3.2.0",
  "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-nop" % "1.6.4",
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick-hikaricp" % "3.2.0"
```

Added the following to my build.sbt:

```
javaOptions in Test +="-Dlogger.file=conf/logback.xml"
```

And made sure that there is a logger.xml in the conf/ folder of my application! **Please note** that this file should be called **logback.xml**, or should start with logback like **logback-test.xml** otherwise it does not work!

This is how I call my sbt when running unit tests:

```
sbt clean test
```

Comment: When you put logback-test.xml to test classpath, like to src/test/resources, you don't even have to add the logger.file option, the file should be found automatically.